# Pymongo sort error

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have been trying to sort documents in Mongo collection by ObjectId in descending order from Pymongo and use the last added record using this code

```
record = collection.find({}).sort('_id', -1).limit(1)
```

However, I am getting 'expected a character buffer object'error. Not sure what is happening here.
Also, if anyone can think of a better way to get the last added record from mongo collection using Pymongo, it will be great help.

Comment: Whats the datatype for your _id, is it a string, number, object or ObjectId.

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in collection.find().sort("_id", pymongo.DESCENDING).limit(1):
    # do something with your item.
```

Comment: Gives an error "find/rfind/index/rindex() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)"

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, PyMongo driver and it details. But when I working with it in past, this code working good. Try to use `find({})` instead of `find()` to avoid this error.

Comment: @Ivan.Srb value of pymongo.DESCENDING is -1. Thats not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates to me that your "collection" variable holds a string, not a PyMongo Collection instance. I need to see the code that sets the "collection" variable to know what mistake you're making. But let's start from the top:

```
import pymongo
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
collection = client.db
cursor = collection.find({}).sort('_id', -1).limit(1)
record = cursor.next()
```

This will get you a recently-added document, but not always the *most* recently added. The [timestamp portion of an ObjectId](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/object-id/) is only precise to one second, and since it's generated on the client machine that inserts the document, ObjectId is subject to clock skew.

If and only if the collection is [capped](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/capped-collections/), you can reliably get the last document like:

```
cursor = collection.find({}).sort('$natural', -1).limit(1)
record = cursor.next()
```